# Как вытянуть из строки только цифры?

Tags: php

Есть строки вида 'abc 72', 'cdi 8', 'bagi 993' и т.д. Мне нужно из каждой такой строки вытянуть только цифры и привести их к типу 'int'. Знаю, что php автоматом приводит к нужному типу, но здесь у меня почему-то не получается. Как решить проблему (без использования регулярки, только средствами php)? Спасибо

Comment: Формат всегда строго такой — один пробел и только цифры после пробела?

Comment: Как правило, да

Answer (score 0):

Коллеги, неравнодушные люди подсказали подходящее решение - функция 'filter_var()'
Перевод переменной, содержащей цифры, исключительно в digits будет выглядеть так:

```
(int) filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)
```

Может быть, это также кому-то окажется полезным